# Set the minimum and the mazimum size of the NS window Controller in mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am making an app for Mac OSX but I have noticed that user can keep minimizing the size of the window. I want to set a minimum and the maximum size of the window controller. I have checked the attributes inspector property but you cannot set it from there. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "Size" tab, you can find there settings for the minimum and the maximum size you want to allow for your window.

[image]